# Parsing Nested Json objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I am new in Javascript, and I want to know how to parse json objects.

I have a Json object similar to this

```
{ "M":{"mot":"abandonner"}, "CONT":"N f preuve p", "DOM":{"nom":"sociologie"}, "OP":"car",
 "SENS":"quitter,délaisser", "OP1":"H2a1", "CA":{"categorie":"Vt"}}
```

And I want to parse a json file in javascript and send the result to

```
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/word/listWords2", true);
```

my function:

```
function addListBdd() {
var inputFile = document.getElementById('inputFile').files[0];

var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (event) { 
        var resultRest = reader.result;
        var json = JSON.parse(resultRest);
        var result = [];
       for(var i=0; i<json.length;i++){
            var obj = json[i];
            //TO DO
       }
    };

    reader.readAsText(inputFile);
}
```

edit HTML code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                            <h2 class="font-weight-light">Liste de mots à ajouter</h2>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="FichierAdd">Fichier</label>
                                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="inputFile" name="myFile"><br>
                                <button onclick="addListBdd()" type="button" class="btn btn-success center-block" >Ajouter la liste</button>
                            </div><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: you seem to have all the knowledge required to do this, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: `json.length` is only valid if the json object is an Array. Try `i<Object.keys(json).length` instead, then in the loop use `obj = json[Object.keys(json)[i]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FormData` to send files (see [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) or [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)) or strings to a server. There is a great introduction on MDN. If you want to send something else you have to convert it into one of these datatypes first. For an object like yours you can convert it back to a string using `JSON.stringfy()` and then parse it on the server side.

> #### [MDN: Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

You don't described how the data should be send with the POST method so I just make a general example how to use it:

```js
var formData = new FormData();

// add a string
formData.append('A_FORMDATA_ATTRIBUTE', 'A TEXT AS STRING');
// add a file
var exampleFile = new Blob(['<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'], {type : 'text/html'});
formData.append('ANOTHER_ATTRIBUTE', exampleFile);

// send the data
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/word/listWords2", true);
request.send(formData);
```

**Edit:**
The best way to transfer structured data (like an array with objects) to the server side would be to send a `.json` file as the request body. This can be done directly without `FormData`. The server has to read the request body and parse the JSON in whatever structure he needs.

```js
// object that needs to be transmitted
var body = [{
    "M":{"mot":"abandonner"},
    "CONT":"N f preuve p",
    "DOM":{"nom":"sociologie"},
    "OP":"car",
    "SENS":"quitter,délaisser",
    "OP1":"H2a1",
    "CA":{"categorie":"Vt"}
  }, {
    "M":{"mot":"abandonner"},
    "CONT":"N f preuve p",
    "DOM":{"nom":"sociologie"},
    "OP":"car",
    "SENS":"quitter,délaisser",
    "OP1":"H2a1",
    "CA":{"categorie":"Vt"}
  }];

// open connection
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/word/listWords2", true);
// set content type to JSON 
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
// attach the body as a string
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body));
```

Comment: the post method contains a request body with list of words (@RequestBody List<Word> words) and the model Word contains attributes : String M, String CONT, String DOM, String OP, String SENS , String OP1, String CA.    How can I parse M DOM and CA ? thanks in advance

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer. If that was helpful and you used this answer to solve your problem, it would be nice if you mark that answer as accepted. Of cause only if you want. It would not only help me but also others who have the same problem and come across this question while searching. If something is still unclear, please ask again.